# how to join 2 tables but have the same result count as table a

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

here is the dilemma i am having...

i have 2 tables

```
create table #orders
(orderNumber int,qty int,sku varchar(250),barcode varchar(250))

create table #allItemsInBox
([id] int,[date] date,[localsku] varchar(250),[box] varchar(250),barcode varchar(250))
```

i need to join the 2 tables on `[barcode]` and only have 1 result in the final table for every row in `#allItemsInBox`

please note `[#allItemsInBox].[id]` is unique the other fields in `[#allItemsInBox]` may not be

how would i go about doing something like this?

```
sample data:
[#orders]
(1,0,'10','10') 
(1,0,'20','20')
(3,0,'20','20')
(4,0,'30','30')
(5,0,'40','40')
(6,0,'50','50')

#allItemsInBox
(1,'12/3/2014',10,'Box1',10)
(2,'12/2/2014',20,'Box2',20)
(3,'12/1/2014',20,'Box3',20)
(4,'11/30/2014',20,'Box4',20)
(5,'11/29/2014',30,'Box5',30)
(6,'11/28/2014',40,'Box6',40)
(7,'11/27/2014',60,'Box8',60)
(8,'11/27/2014',50,'Box10',50)

#output
(ordernumber int,uniqueitemID int,localsku varchar(250),box varchar(250))
(1,1,10,'Box1')
(1,2,20,'Box2')
(3,3,10,'Box3')
(4,5,30,'Box5')
(5,6,40,'Box6')
(6,8,50,'Box10')
```

Comment: How do you want to display when there are multiple orders with the same barcode?  Count them?

Comment: each item on each order must have a unique `[#allItemsInBox].[id]`

Comment: Can you post sample data along with desired output.

Comment: i have added some sample data

Comment: i am thinking i might just have to use a pointer and loop through all the results one at a time....

Comment: but in you #output you don't have only have 1 result in the final table for every row in #allItemsInBox

Comment: no there will not always be a result for every `#allItemsInBox`

Comment: Then make the question more clear on what you mean by "i need to join the 2 tables on [barcode] and only have 1 result in the final table for every row in #allItemsInBox"

Comment: i am basically creating a pick list
each item has an unique item number barcode and sku 
i have orders... each order must be filled but only recieve and get a single item and items cannot be 'reused'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quick but works. Depending on the size of your data this might be not the best way performance wise. But this will give you a start

```
DECLARE @orders TABLE (
    orderNumber int,
    qty int,
    sku varchar(250),
    barcode varchar(250)
)


DECLARE @allItemsInBox TABLE (
    [id] int,
    [date] date,
    [localsku] varchar(250),
    [box] varchar(250),
    barcode varchar(250)
)

 INSERT INTO @orders VALUES
    (1,0,'10','10'),
    (1,0,'20','20'),
    (3,0,'20','20'),
    (4,0,'30','30'),
    (5,0,'40','40'),
    (6,0,'50','50')

 INSERT INTO @allItemsInBox VALUES
    (1,'2014-12-03',10,'Box1',10),
    (2,'2014-12-02',20,'Box2',20),
    (3,'2014-12-01',20,'Box3',20),
    (4,'2014-11-30',20,'Box4',20),
    (5,'2014-11-29',30,'Box5',30),
    (6,'2014-11-28',40,'Box6',40),
    (7,'2014-11-27',60,'Box8',60),
    (8,'2014-11-27',50,'Box10',50)

SELECT
    orders.orderNumber AS ordernumber 
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 allItems.id FROM @allItemsInBox allItems WHERE allItems.barcode = orders.barcode AND allItems.id >= orders.orderNumber ORDER BY allItems.id) AS uniqueitemID 
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 allItems.localsku FROM @allItemsInBox allItems WHERE allItems.barcode = orders.barcode AND allItems.id >= orders.orderNumber ORDER BY allItems.id) AS localsku
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 allItems.box FROM @allItemsInBox allItems WHERE allItems.barcode = orders.barcode AND allItems.id >= orders.orderNumber ORDER BY allItems.id) AS box
FROM
    @orders orders
```

Results in:

```
ordernumber uniqueitemID    localsku    box
1   1   10  Box1
1   2   20  Box2
3   3   20  Box3
4   5   30  Box5
5   6   40  Box6
6   8   50  Box10
```

**edit:** I updated the answer. You now have the same output as you specified in your example/question

Comment: in this case i unique id for ordernumber 1 and 3 is the same... it would have to be different...

Comment: i ran this with different items/orders and found when a 2 orders have the same items on them i get the same item back

Comment: the please specify what you want exactly. I am confused